# Cloudbuild template and env file

Tags: symfony, yaml, gitlab-ci, google-cloud-build

I'm on Symfony but It's not very important. I have a .env file and I would like to use his variables in cloudbuild.yaml. There is no way to avoid duplication  ? 
Moreover, I read this [article](https://itnext.io/building-continuous-delivery-pipeline-2cc05e213935) and I saw that author use Yaml merge feature [with gitlab hidden key](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#special-yaml-features), its very useful when the file is big. I try to use this but cloud build not like, it seems to be impossible to use custom key like in gitlab-ci.yaml. Any Idea ?

- UPDATE

In build we need to have env variables and generic config file to avoid to change a lot of value manually. So I would like to use hidden keys in cloudbuild.yaml because I need to use Yaml merge feature for avoid code duplication.
This is my cloudbuild.yaml example without optimisation :

```yaml
steps:
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
    args: ['build', '-t', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/image-pgsql', '-f', 'docker/postgresql/Dockerfile', '.']
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
    args: ['build', '-t', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/image-nginx', '--build-arg', 'VERSION=1.15.3', '-f', 'docker/nginx/Dockerfile', '.']
```

But I would like to have this, or something like that :

```yaml
.build-template: &buildTemplate
  args: ['build', '-t', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/${IMAGE_NAME}', '--build-arg', 'VERSION=${VERSION}', '-f', '${DOCKER_PATH}', '.']

steps:
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    <<: *buildTemplate
    env: ['IMAGE_NAME=pgsql', 'VERSION=12', 'DOCKER_PATH=docker/postgresql/Dockerfile']
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    <<: *buildTemplate
    env: ['IMAGE_NAME=nginx', 'VERSION=1.15.3', 'DOCKER_PATH=docker/nginx/Dockerfile']
```

I get this when I try to run `cloud-build-local --dryrun=false  .` =>

```
Error loading config file: unknown field ".build-template" in cloudbuild.Build
```

Comment: Following the article, what error it gives you? Do you want to implement hidden keys in Cloud Build? Could you please explain in detail what are you trying to do and what errors you are facing? Could you please explain what do you mean by duplication?

Comment: @NibrassH Post updated sorry

Answer (score 3):

You have to follow the cloudbuild.yaml schema, which is documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/build-config). Since a build would be directly triggered from that yaml file, it is not possible to add other fields and do some sort of pre-processing to merge different files together.

The only options that are on the table as we speak:

1. Use global environment variables:

   ```
   options:
     env: [string, string, ...]
   steps: [...]
   ```
2. Use step-specific environment variables:

   ```
   steps:
     - name: string
       env: [string, string, ...]
   ```
3. Use substitution (with allow-loose):

   ```
    substitutions:
        _SUB_VALUE: world
    options:
        substitution_option: 'ALLOW_LOOSE'
    steps:
      - name: 'ubuntu'
        args: ['echo', 'hello ${_SUB_VALUE}']
   ```
4. Source your `[environment].env` file in a build step:

   ```
    steps:
      - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
        entrypoint: 'bash'
        args:
          - '-c'
          - |
            source ${BRANCH_NAME}.env
            echo $${_MY_VARIABLE_1}
            echo $${_MY_VARIABLE_2}
            ...
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, Google Cloud Build doesn't have this feature of hidden keys in Cloud build. I have create a Feature Request in [Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/152180846) on your behalf where you can track all the updates related to the feature request of hidden keys in Cloud Build.